# How to insert multiple value onkey change action?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, ajax, codeigniter

Hi I am using codeigniter framework. I already done a autofill action with onkey change.I used ajax to post a id value to my controller function that will fetch a single data row from service table.
Now I have more than 1 record ow row which is having same id. For example,

```
+----+-----------------+------+
+  1 +  iPhone6        +   2  +
+----+-----------------+------+
+  1 +  ipod           +   5  +
+----+-----------------+------+
```

Here I have 2 rows that has the same Id now when I post the id value then I need to get both the data and display in my view page.
For this I need to add rows in table accordingly.

**My controller function**

```
<?php
class Admin_billing extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('billing_model');

    }
 public function getdetails()
     {  
        $data_to_search=$_POST['val'];
        $details=array();

        $details['description']=$this->billing_model->get_service_name($data_to_search);
        $details['type']=$this->billing_model->get_service_name($data_to_search);
        $details['price']=$this->billing_model->get_service_pricevalue($data_to_search);

        echo json_encode($details);
     }
    }
```

Here I have a `getdetails()` that has a array `details`. In that details array I have key and value for single data such as it can hold data like
`description=>phone order, type=> iphone, price => $7000`. This fills the data in my view page. Now if I have more than one row how to make it work?

**My model function**

```
public function get_service_name($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('service');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result[0]['name']; 
}
```

This function is used to get the name from service table in my database.

**My view file.**

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-compat-git.js'></script>
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-ui.js" ></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
var baseurl='<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
$(function() {
    $('#test').on('change', 'input[name="pid[]"]', function() {
        var indexOfTheChangedRow = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        get_values(this.value, indexOfTheChangedRow);
    });
});

function get_values(val,rowIndex)
{
 $.ajax({
    url: baseurl + 'admin/billing/getdetails',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        val: val
    },
    success: function (indexOfTheChangedRow, response) {
        if (response != "") {
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response),
                rowToUpdate = $("#test tr:nth-child(" + (indexOfTheChangedRow + 1) + ")");
            $('.description', rowToUpdate).val(json.description);
            $('.type', rowToUpdate).val(json.type);

        }
    }.bind(window, rowIndex),
    error: function (response) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
}

function displayResult() {
<?php

      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
      $options_employee = array('' => "Select");
      foreach ($employee as $row)
      {
        $options_employee[$row['first_name']] = $row['first_name'];
      }
    $dropdown = form_dropdown('employee[]', $options_employee, set_value('employee[]'), 'class="span2"');

      ?>

    var complex = <?php echo json_encode($dropdown); ?>;

    var row = document.getElementById("test").insertRow(-1);
    row.innerHTML = '<td><div>'+complex+'</div></td><td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="pid[]" onclick="BindControls()" id="pid" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="type[]" class="type" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td>';
}
</script>

</head>


<body>
<?php

      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
      $options_employee = array('' => "Select");
      foreach ($employee as $row)
      {
        $options_employee[$row['first_name']] = $row['first_name'];
      }
 echo form_open('admin/billing/add_tickets');
      ?>
            <div id="form"> 
             <!-- div form starts here.its for add table  -->
            <table id="test">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <td>Employee</td>
            <td>Start Time</td>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Type</td>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo form_dropdown('employee[]', $options_employee, set_value('employee[]'), 'class="span2"');?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pid[]" id="pid" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="type[]" class="type" style="width:45px;"/></td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>

            <div id="add_row">
        <button type="button" onClick="displayResult()" class="add_r"></button>
                </div>

  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/function.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This my view page here I have a table with id test and this table consist of row with input elements in each cell.I have a add row button that calls a javascript function to add row dynamically.In this table I have a input element with `id="pid[]"` when `key change` action happens it calls a ajax function and get value from the database.
This works fine for single record. When I have multiple record I am struck up with no clear Idea.

1.I need to get a array of data.

2.add rows dynamically and fill data in all rows added in one key change action.

Can someone please help me code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could not understand your comment. Can you please explain? @NiranjanNRaju

Comment: Only post relevant part in view without paste whole page in to this

Comment: Sorry i gave my view page only part of it to make my code more understandable i explained at last @Abdulla

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT: Once you have got the array, simply json_encode() and send back to the ajax. There you can decode it back. You also need to use this in your ajax : dataType : 'json'**

**Also note that we are setting key 'error' in the php and returnig $data array, if there was an error and checking the value in the success() of ajax to deduce if there was an error or not.**

Javascript: Note this is striped down version of what you will do, but it serves the purpose of what you need to do. Hope it helps.

```
$.ajax ( { method : 'POST',url : scriptUrl,data : data,
    cache : false, processData: false, /** Don't process the data **/
    contentType: false, /** Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request **/
    dataType : 'json', /** we will return data in the key-value format from the php file **/
    success : function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) { /** We can treat the returned data as object. **/
        if ( typeof data.error === 'undefined' ) { /** damn error **/ }
        else { /** We got our data. **/
            for (var key in data) {
                alert(key + " -> " + data[key]);
            }
        }
    }
```

This should work for all your queries irrespective of number of records and number of columns.

```
$query = $this->db->get();

/** Check for return value
    If there is an error, set error key, we will use it in the ajax to
    check if there was an error at the bancend 
 */

if ( ! $query ) { $data['error'] = TRUE; return $data; }

/**
 * Array to hold our data.
 * For reference look at the foreach() loop.
 */

$data = array (  );

/** Get each record as $row. **/
foreach ( $query->result (  ) as $row )
{

    /**
     * Temporary array to hold the data of this record.
     */
    $temp = array (  );

    /** Get each value as $key => $value pair **/
    foreach ( $row as $key => $value)
    {
        $temp [ $key ] = $value;
    }    
    array_push ( $data, $temp );
}
return $data;
```

Now $data is an multidimensional associative arrays, $data[0] is equals to one record `array ( 'id' =>1, 'name' => 'something'... );`

```
$data = array ( array ( 'id' =>1, 'name' => 'something'... ), ( 'id' =>1, 'name' => 'something'... ),.... );
```

Comment: thank you. But my problem is not to get multiple record. I need to display them in my view page and add row according to the number of record found. @StudentX

Comment: Can you please guide me with ajax and json, That is the actual place i stuck up!! :( @StudentX

Comment: @Anu Have a look at the updated answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Query is returning null. I couldnt proceed anymore @StudentX

Comment: @Anu In that case you need to look at your database query. You can use $this->db->last_query(); to get if your query string is forming the way you want it.

Answer (score 3):

1. On change in any value of the row fetch all the sibling values having same names
2. Say if you changed the amount in row 4 inside on change function fetch the values of all the n rows and form an object such as

   var a = "[{
          "key1"=>"value1",
          "key2"=>"value2",
          "key3"=>"value3",
          "key4"=>"value4"
       },{
          "key1"=>"value1",
          "key2"=>"value2",
          "key3"=>"value3",
          "key4"=>"value4"
       },{
          "key1"=>"value1",
          "key2"=>"value2",
          "key3"=>"value3",
          "key4"=>"value4"
       },
   ]"
3. and post this to PHP
4. In PHP read this array and using foreach loop parse the array and insert (if it is a new record), update (if it was an existing record) and delete (all the record which are there already in database but not in the current array) each record in your database

Answer (score 2):

To get multiple records for given value,you have to change your model code.Replace your code with following code in your model:

```
public function get_service_name($id)
{
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->from('service');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result; // It will provide you array of all service name having id=$id 
}
```

Comment: Thats fine. How to bring those data to view page? Any ideas please?